# Subgrid not getting populated in free jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am trying to add subgrid to every row of main grid. The main grid populates fine but when i click on the expand icon of a row subgrid is not populated. Only subgrid column headers appear. 
The json data is a single nested data structure which is fetched only once when grid loads first time. So when i click on the grid expand icon i expect subgrid to be populated from the data that was fetched while displaying the parent grid. 
The empty subgrid is displayed when i use - datatype: "local". 
If i set datatype: "json" then a server side call is made to fetch data if i click on expand icon. 
So how can i display subgrid using the single json data that was already fetched. Thanks 
Please find sample code below,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
    var dataGrid = $('#itemList');
    var firstClick = true;
    $('#action').click(function () {
        if (!firstClick) {
            $("#itemList").setGridParam({datatype:'json'}).trigger("reloadGrid");
        }   
        firstClick = false;
    $("#itemList").jqGrid({
        url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/billing/items",
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: "POST",
        autowidth: true,
        loadBeforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
             jqXHR.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", $("input[name='_csrf']").val());
        },
        colNames: ["Id", "Item Type", "Item Code"],
        colModel: [
            { name: "id", width: 35, sorttype:"int", search: false, editable: false, key: true, hidden: true},
            { name: "itemType", width: 100},
            { name: "itemCode", width: 120}

        ],
        maxHeight: 400,
        cmTemplate: {editable: true},
        pager: true,
        rowNum: 50,
        rowList: [50, 100, 150, 200],
        rownumbers: true,
        rownumWidth: 25,
        sortname: "itemType",
        sortorder: "asc",
        forceClientSorting: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        height: '100%',
        loadonce: true,
        //gridview: true,
        autoencode: true,
        editurl: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/billing/saveItem",
        caption: "Item List",
        subGrid: true,
        subGridRowExpanded: function (subgridId, rowid) {
            var subgridTableId = subgridId + "_t";
            $("#" + subgridId).html("<table id='" + subgridTableId + "'></table>");
            $("#" + subgridTableId).jqGrid({
                datatype: "local",
                data: $(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowid).itemDetails,
                colNames: ["Id", "Unit", "Stock", "Batch No.", "Expiry Date", "Quantity Per Unit", "Price"],
                colModel: [
                    { name: "id", width: 35, sorttype:"int", search: false, editable: false, key: true, hidden: true},       
                    { name: "unit", width: 70, search: false},
                    { name: "availableQuantity", width: 55, search: false, formatter: "number",},
                    { name: "batchNumber", width: 80, search: false},
                    { name: "expiryDate", width: 80, search: false, sorttype: "date", formatoptions: {srcformat:'d/m/Y', newformat:'d/m/Y'}},
                    { name: "quantityPerUnit", width: 80, search: false, formatter: "number"},
                    { name: "price", width: 55, search: false, formatter: "number"}
                ],
                height: "100%",
                rowNum: 10,                    
                idPrefix: "s_" + rowid + "_",
                cmTemplate: {editable: true},
                editurl: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/billing/saveItem"
            });
        }            
    }).navGrid({add:false,edit:false,del:true});
    $("#itemList").jqGrid('filterToolbar', {autoSearch: true, stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: 'cn'});
    $("#itemList").jqGrid('gridResize', { minWidth: 450, minHeight: 150 });
});
```

The sample json data:-

```
[{"id":1,"itemCode":"Omez","itemType":"Medicine","itemDesc":"Omez for acidity","itemDetails":[{"id":1,"batchNumber":"batch1","expiryDate":"01/06/2018","unit":"bottle","subUnit":"tablet","availableQuantity":120.0,"quantityPerUnit":60.0,"price":122.0}]}]
```

Comment: You use `$(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowid).itemDetails`. Is `itemDetails` property included in every row of the data (returned from `"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/billing/items"`)? You use `forceClientSorting: true` and `maxHeight: 400` options. Do you use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid)? In the case you should include `free-jqgrid` tag to the question additionally to `jqgrid`. You use hidden column `name: "id"`. Do you need to display the column later to the user? If not then you can remove the column. What is the meaning of `firstClick` and `#action`?

Comment: Hello Oleg, yes, i use free jqGrid. itemDetails property is included with every row of the data. 'id' column is hidden because i want to act it as a hidden variable so that it get's sent to server when i edit the row. 'firstClick' variable is being used so that grid is loaded only once when user hits 'action' button. And on subsequent hits on 'action' grid will be re-loaded using 'trigger("reloadGrid")'

Comment: I have added sample json data to the question. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it's important to understand that the data, returned from `url` will be read and saved locally in case of usage `loadonce: true` option of jqGrid. By default it read only the data for the columns of the grid and the property `id` (can be configured by `id` property of `prmNames` parameter). Free jqGrid allows to read and save any other additional properties. To specify the properties one can use `additionalProperties`. The simplest for of the usage would be

```
additionalProperties: ["itemDetails"]
```

It informs jqGrid to read and save locally `itemDetails` property of every item. After that `$(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowid).itemDetails` will work.

Additionally you can remove the column `id` from `colModel`. jqGrid set `id` attribute of the rows based on the value of `id` property of input data (returned from the server). Thus you don't need to hold the duplicate information in hidden `<td>` cell of every row. You can remove the `id` column from both main grid and the subgrid.

If you want to set `search: false` for all columns of subgrid then you can use `cmTemplate: {search: false}` option of subgrid and remove `search: false` from all columns. In the same way you can include in `cmTemplate` the property `width: 80` (`cmTemplate: {search: false, width: 80}`) to change the default value 150 for the `width` property to 80. After that you can remove `width: 80` from tree columns of subdrid too.

You can remove `sortorder: "asc"` and `height: '100%'` properties, because there are default for free jqGrid. You can use

```
searching: {
    stringResult: true,
    searchOnEnter: false,
    defaultSearch: 'cn'
}
```

The property `autosearch: true` (not `autoSearch: true`) are default. After that you can use `filterToolbar` without additional parameters.

I would recommend you to use additional option of `navGrid`: `reloadGridOptions: { fromServer: true }` which informs to reload the data from the server (by restoring original value of `datatype`) if the user clicks on Refresh button of navigator bar.

Comment: Thank you Oleg for detailed reply. I will try your suggested changes and let you know.